# How do I check if mod_fcgi is enabled in Apache and/or how to enable it?

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, mod-fcgid

I have a VPS with CENTOS 5.7 . We are using Apache 2.2.22 and mod_fcgi is supposed to be running according to WHM.

1. I did a `httpd -l` and mod_fcgid.c was not listed there.
2. I checked the httpd.conf file and /usr/local/apache/conf/php.conf is included.
3. I also checked that php.conf file and `LoadModule fcgid_module modules/mod_fcgid.so` is there, so I think it should be enabled.

When I try to configure mod_fcgid with parameters like

```
MaxRequestsPerProcess 500
MaxProcessCount 5
```

I write them in the php.conf file and there is no change at all, I have more than 5 php processes in `top`. Maybe I don't understand how mod_fcgi works ?

How can I check if mod_fcgid is enabled and how can I test it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `apachectl -t -D DUMP_MODULES` to show the modules in the currently running configuration.

Note that mod_fcgid isn't in a standard CentOS 5 package.  Instead of compiling it youself, you should enable the karan repo, and install it from there using yum:

http://centos.karan.org/

The RPM itself can be found at:

http://centos.karan.org/el5/extras/testing/i386/RPMS/

but, as said, you should install via yum and let it satisfy dependencies.

Here are some instructions I found:

http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-set-up-apache2-with-mod_fcgid-and-php5-on-centos-5.2

I haven't tested them, but, on the face of it, they look like they should work.